# Error while creating android release build from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I'm trying to generate apk using `Android tools > Export Signed apllication project`, but I'm getting this error:

```
Proguard return with error code 1. See console
```

Console says:

```
[2013-08-21 17:03:56 - DisplayMetrics] Warning: there were 23 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2013-08-21 17:03:56 - DisplayMetrics]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2013-08-21 17:03:56 - DisplayMetrics] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-08-21 17:03:56 - DisplayMetrics]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2013-08-21 17:03:56 - DisplayMetrics]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2013-08-21 17:03:56 - DisplayMetrics]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2013-08-21 17:03:56 - DisplayMetrics]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

This is happening from the time I added 3 jar files in `libs` folder. How can I fix this?

Comment: are you using Proguard during application export? is proguard config file included in your project?

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji Yes it is

Comment: seems like you are using Proguard (maybe it was enabled automatically for you), and you have to include your libraries into Proguard config file. Add this line to Proguard config file "-libraryjars /libs/your_library_name.jar"

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji I tried adding, still the same error. Are you talking about `{sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt` this file?